# Remove "Install Ubuntu" menu on persistent USB stick?

Tags: 12.04, live-usb

I used the Lili software to create a persistent live Ubuntu install on my usb stick, and everything appears to be running fine. However, whenever I boot the PC, Ubuntu always prompts me with the "Install Ubuntu" (or try it) menu, instead of sending me to a login screen.

I've already added a couple new user accounts, and I created some test files to ensure the persistent memory is working, but I can't find a way to disable the menu.

Is there a way to remove that menu without actually installing to the usb stick (and to just keep it in persistent live mode)?

Comment: The best solution is to do a full install on an USB stick or hard drive. You can do it from a live DVD or another USB stick. In case you use two USB sticks, make sure you install on the correct one and GRUB is also installed on the correct stick.

Comment: But that would both cause more writing to the flash drive, and would potentially slow down the OS if the drive speed is slow, right?

Comment: You are writing to the flash drive in any case in the persistent install when you are creating new users adding data etc. I don't think it will slow down the drive or the OS.

Answer (score 0):

it because its not currently installed system its still live usb (even if it unlike ubuntu live dvd save your settings)and that is because everytime this menu appears.If you install ubuntu  from usb stick to hard drive you wont get this menu

Comment: I am aware of that. I want to keep it as a live usb (since I can't write to the disk on the computer I'm using).

Comment: then you ll have to deal with  menu or maybe you can manage boot loader and set display timeout  while booting